# Jquery Ui AutoComplete is not working with keyup/down when used with label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

When using keyup keydown to select option from autocomplete list textbox is showing value. But incase of selection from mouse it is working properly. 
JsFiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/0c21r1pe/1

```
$("#promoteActionTextBox").autocomplete({
        source: actionNames,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $('#promoteActionError').hide();
            $(this).attr('actionId', ui.item.value);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
            else {

                $('#promoteActionError').hide();
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $(this).attr('actionId', ui.item.value);
            }
        }
    }).focus(function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#promoteActionTextBox').autocomplete("search");
        this.value = ui.item.label;
    });
```

Comment: @Innovarion - My jsfiffle link - http://jsfiddle.net/0c21r1pe/1/

Comment: There is problem with value change it into something like avalue then it will work

Answer (score 4):

change the object property name from `value` to something else and it works

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/0c21r1pe/2/)

**UPDATE**

How about [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/0c21r1pe/3/)

I added a code which removes the event which is responsible for that effect.

```
create:function(){
    $('.ui-autocomplete').unbind('menufocus');
}
```

Comment: Behavior is different with keypress and mouse. Incase of key press I can see values in textbox. which I don't need

Answer (score 0):

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Add on keyboard keyup, keydown is working well
    $("#id_value").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#id_label").val(ui.item.label);
},
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Add on keyboard keyup, keydown is working well
    $("#id_value").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#id_label").val(ui.item.label);
}
```